# Have python open .py files in the path without having to associate .py files with the interpreter (windows)

Tags: windows, command-line, python, file-association

I like having my .py files open with my IDE, PyScripter. That is, when I double-click on a .py file, it opens in my IDE.

The problem is that when I want to run a python script that isn't in the current directory (e.g. it is in c:\Python27\Scripts), I can't do `python script_in_path.py` or I get the error

> Can't open file 'script_in_path.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

If I change the file association for .py files (e.g. by right-clicking, open with, always use python), I can do `script_in_path.py` with no problem. But I don't want .py files associated with the python interpreter!

How can I make `python script_in_path.py` work while still having .py files associated with my IDE?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299241/cant-open-file-django-admin-py-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory is related, except the answers all boil down to associating .py files with the interpreter, which is what I **do not** want to do.

Answer (score 0):

ah, like a path command for data files / like having other directories treated as current directory. don't know.. I often use pushd. `C:\agrap>pushd c:\blah\long\otherdir <ENTER>` then I can change back to the previous directory with popd. Or you could use doskey macros `C:\>doskey abc=cd c:\windows <ENTER>` `C:\>doskey abcd=cd c:\program files <ENTER>` then do `abc<ENTER> or abcd<ENTER>` to go from one directory to another. Or a batch file to change dir. Funnily enough, there is  [the append command](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/append.mspx?mfr=true) , an ancient DOS command, but

I don't think it works in NT, at least not in XP.

> http://pcsupport.about.com/od/commandlinereference/tp/command-prompt-commands-p1.htm
>
> Append
>
> The append command can be used by programs to open files in another
>   directory as if they were located in the current directory.
>
> The append command is available in MS-DOS as well as in all 32-bit
>   versions of Windows. The append command is not available in 64-bit
>   versions of Windows.
>
> http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/append.mspx?mfr=true
>
> Append Enables programs to open data files in specified folders as if
>   these files were in the current folder. Used without parameters,
>   append displays the appended directory list. Windows XP does not use
>   this command. It is accepted only for compatibility with MS-DOS files.

So I can only see those workarounds to the old DOS append command.  pushd popd, or doskey macros. or a batch file. or 2 cmd windows one in one directory one in another.  Or specifying the full path of the data file. Or writing a bat file python.bat or mypython.bat that tries each directory to see if the file is there and runs it where it exists!

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately, I've resorted to making redirecting/alias batch files (a la Chocolatey) for the really often used scripts. But it's not ideal.